# Insertion Sort running time calculating using summtion

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

I was reading Introduction to algorithms, and stopped at the calculating the running time.

> For each $j = 2,3,..,n$ where $n = A.length$, we let $t_j$ denote the number of times the while loop test in line $5$ is executed for that value of $j$ .

so I don't understand this statements with the sums and why the lines 6,7 it takes $t_j-1$

[image: Running time of Insertion Sort]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix a value of $j$, i.e., an iteration of the outer loop.
If the condition of the while loop at line 5 is tested $t_j$ times during this iteration  (as per definition) then it must be false exactly once. In particular, it must be false in the last of the $t_j$ tests, which causes the inner while loop to terminate.

As a consequence, each instruction in the body of the inner while loop is executed $t_j - 1$ times. Summing the above expression over all considered values of $j$ (from $2$ to $n$) yields $\sum_{i=2}^n (t_j - 1)$.

Comment: ($t_j$ is data dependant with extremes (which?) for ascending and descending input.)

Comment: ah thanks, so tj will be executed for While-Loop even if it's false but for the statements inside it it will be tj -1 since it won't execute if it's false, right ? and in the calculating the sums can we ignore the first one and just calculate the inner ones since they are more important ?